# ESRI Converting JSON Object to Polygon Object

Tags: polygon, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geometry, json

I am using require.js

```
// output of polygonString is
// {"spatialReference":{"latestWkid":3414,"wkid":3414},"rings":[[[18240.432900000364,43817.389900000766],[18214.047899999656,43880.139900000766],[18303.02390000038,43896.1548999995],[18316.83990000002,43898.6389000006],[18331.732900000177,43815.97389999963],[18247.076899999753,43800.71189999953],[18240.432900000364,43817.389900000766]]]}
var polygon = JSON.parse($parameters.polygonString)
```

I am trying to convert the JSON object to a ESRI Polygon object, I had tried the following:

(1)

```
//doesn't seems to work
var new_polygon = new window.ArcGIS.Polygon({
      fromJSON: polygon
});
```

(2)

```
//return fromJSON is not a function
var new_polygon = new window.ArcGIS.Polygon();
console.log(new_polygon.fromJSON(polygon));
```

What is the correct way to use fromJSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way would be,

```
var polyJson = JSON.parse($parameters.polygonString);
var poly = Polygon.fromJSON(polyJson);
```

Take a look here [ArcGIS Docs - Using fromJSON](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/programming-patterns/#using-fromjson)

Comment: great, it works.. cheers

Comment: glad it help you!